# javafx SwingNode not working until window is resized

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-8

I have been trying the SwingNode from JavaFX8 using this code.  The problem is when the window appears I can not click the button, until I have resized  the window.  Moving it does not work.  I need to either maximize it or resize it with the mouse to get the button to respond.

I realize this could be a bug given that javafx8 is still in beta, but if thats not the case is there something I need to do to make this work with out resizing the window first?

```
    public class SwingNodeTest extends Application {

    private SwingNode swingNode;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        swingNode = new SwingNode();    
        createAndSetSwingContent();    
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);    
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 100, 50));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createAndSetSwingContent() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swingNode.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"));
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);           
    }
}
```

Comment: This code worked fine (could click the JButton immediately the window was first shown) on Java 8 build 101 running on OS X 10.8.4 with a 2012 Macbook Air.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Java 8 build 129. however, my code within invokeLater is more complicated than a button and still doesn't work after my window is resized.  (Also, in another question, I was informed that Platform.runLater should be used instead of SwingUtilities.invokeLater... the latter doesn't work with JavaFX) (I'm using JavaFX/Java 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is simplistic, so it is most likely a bug in the beta.