# JavaFX Windows needs resize to display content

Tags: java, swing, javafx, window-resize

I have this problem with my JavaFX windows, where I added a Scrollpan containing a graph. When I launch the app I need to resize the windows so that the content appears.

Here is the Model:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


    <?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
    <VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" prefHeight="544.0" prefWidth="788.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121"
      fx:controller="Solution.SolutionController">

    <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar">
        <menus>
            <Menu text="File">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem text="Save"/>
                </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
    </MenuBar>

    <VBox fx:id="contenu" alignment="CENTER">

        <HBox alignment="CENTER">

            <ScrollPane style="-fx-background: WHITE" fx:id="pane" focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="608.0"
                        prefWidth="700">
            </ScrollPane>
        </HBox>

        <Label fx:id="counter">

        </Label>
        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="17.0"/>
        </VBox.margin>
    </VBox>

    <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefWidth="690.0">
        <Button onAction="#handleGauche" text="Gauche"/>
        <Button onAction="#handleDroite" text="Droite"/>
    </HBox>

</VBox>
```

Here is the controller:

```
package Solution;

import Main.Individual;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SolutionController {

    public VBox contenu;

    public Label counter;

    public MenuBar menuBar;

    public ScrollPane pane;

    ArrayList<Individual> graph;
    JPanel panel;
    int i;

    public void init() {
        i = 0;

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.add(graph.get(i).chopper.getContentPane());
        panel.validate();
        panel.repaint();

        counter.setText((i+1) + "/" + graph.size());

        SwingNode sn = new SwingNode();
        sn.setContent(panel);
        pane.setContent(sn);
    }

    @FXML
    void handleDroite(ActionEvent event) {
        i = (i + 1) % graph.size();


        changeContent();

    }

    @FXML
    void handleGauche(ActionEvent event) {
        i = (graph.size() + (i - 1)) % graph.size();

        changeContent();
    }

    public void changeContent(){
        counter.setText((i+1) + "/" + graph.size());

        panel.add(graph.get(i).chopper.getContentPane());
        panel.repaint();

        SwingNode sn = new SwingNode();
        sn.setContent(panel);
        pane.setContent(sn);
    }

}
```

And here is the view:

```
package Solution;

import Main.Individual;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SolutionApplication extends Application{
    ArrayList<Individual> graphI;

    public SolutionApplication(ArrayList<Individual> graph) {
        graphI = new ArrayList<>(graph);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Solution.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        SolutionController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.graph = new ArrayList<>(graphI);
        controller.init();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Main Window");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I did stumble on this post
[javafx SwingNode not working until window is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737266/javafx-swingnode-not-working-until-window-is-resized/18157837#18157837)
However they say its a bug with the JDK? I use version 10

I'd like to know how I can fix this.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Just a hunch. Use `revalidate()` instead of `validate()`

Comment: I did. nothing changed, it was actually revalidate before and I changed to validate to try.

Comment: If it can be avoided you shouldn't mix `Swing` and `JavaFx`, so my question is can it be avoided in this case and if not, why not?

Comment: I don't think it can be here, I'm displaying a JGraphT graph inside the scrollpane and since it's built on Swing I don't think it's avoidable. though if you have any alternative I'd be really glad to know about it.